# Call MPI_RECV after certain signal was obtained from the master

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am using a code which runs a loop and accumulates some mean value. At a particular moment in time I would like to send this mean value and receive it on all slaves. This should be done only once. At first glance I taught that this should be fairly easy to do. So I used an internal variable (the loop count) to do the following

```
! on the master
if( i == 55 ) 
do mt = 1, tasks
call MPI_SEND(A,size,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,mt,5,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierror)
end do

! on the slaves
if(i==55) then
call MPI_RECV(a,size,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,5, MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierror)
endif
```

Running this caused segmentation fault, at the line where the MPI_RECV is called. In general this would work if I was communicating continuously, i.e. sending and receiving data during the entire loop.

The most natural thing would be to assume that the variable I am using for triggering the communication is not synchronized between the master and the slaves. Therefore, I decided to send an integer value to the slaves, and use it as a singnal for calling MPI_RECV. Unfortunately this caused a communication deadlock. I did something like:

```
! on the master
sig = 0
if ( i == 55) then 
sig = 1
call MPI_SEND(sig,1,MPI_INTEGER,mt,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierror)
endif

if(i==55) then
do mt =1,tasks
call MPI_SEND(A,size,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,mt,5,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierror)
end do
endif 

! on the slaves
call MPI_RECV(sig,1,MPI_INTEGER,mt,10,MPI_COM_WORLD,status,ierror)
if ( sig == 1) Call MPI_RECV(a,size,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,5,   MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierror)
```

I am not able to figure out what is going on wrong myself.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: (1) Is "I did something like" what your actual code looks like? If not, can you please post the actual relevant part of the code? It it is, then already the first code block doesn't make sense, (2) why mix `MPI_DOUBLE` and `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`, (3) `MPI_COM_WORLD` is going to be undefined and that would go unnoticed if you use implicit typing, the right constant is `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, (4) what types are the other variables, and so on ...

Comment: These were all typos and yes this is the code I used in my program. I made those mistakes, due to being foolish enough not to simply copy-paste the code. I am sorry for the inconvenience. I have modified my question and corrected the typos. The syntax is not the problem.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Your code is still not the actual thing, e.g. comments are placed where the actual distinction of slaves/master should happen. Also, since segfaults can happen due to A/size being wrong, those should certainly also be there. If the code is gigantic, you can try to make a small example that reproduces your problem, and then maybe along the way you might even solve it on your own.

Comment: Well, the distinction between the master and the slaves is governed by the code itself. Therefore I don't need to probe the rank. This is a commercial code and I assume it was correctly done. I think that my mistake could possibly be the lack of definition for the “status”. I have included integer(i4knd),dimension(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: status. And now the segfault has gone for good. Btw, can you recommend a book on MPI (I am interested in the fortran version). I assume that as a professional in the field, you could give me some valuable advice on this.

Comment: why is there a status at all, are you using some wrapper? Since I don't know it all by heart, I went to look it up `MPI_SEND(BUF, COUNT, DATATYPE, DEST, TAG, COMM, IERROR)`, so 7 arguments, you have 8? As for material, I could recommend http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Performance-Computing-Scientists-Computational/dp/143981192X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1394809085&sr=8-1&keywords=introduction+to+high+performance+computing as it covers parallel computing, which is much more than just MPI and it has C/Fortran code samples.

Comment: I am not sure about that either, I copied the syntax from the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to send data from one MPI process to all other MPI processes, using `MPI_SEND` and `MPI_RECV` is horribly inefficient. Take a look at the function [`MPI_BCAST`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Bcast.html). The prototype for this function looks like this:

```
MPI_BCAST(BUFFER, COUNT, DATATYPE, ROOT, COMM, IERROR)
<type>    BUFFER(*)
INTEGER    COUNT, DATATYPE, ROOT, COMM, IERROR
```

At the root process (the master process in your case), you pass the value that you want to send to everyone else in as the `BUFFER`. I assume you're only intending to send one value as the mean so your `COUNT` will be 1. The `DATATYPE` is whatever you want (`MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`), the `ROOT` is your master rank (I assume 0) and your `COMM` is `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

Something important to remember with MPI_BCAST (and all other functions like it called "collective functions") is that every process must make this call together. Until everyone has entered the call, no one will be able to leave it. So make sure that everyone is on the same iteration.

Comment: Note also, that in MPI-3 you can use non-blocking collectives.

Comment: Hi,
I am actually sending a vector with 5000 elements, each one of them being double precision real. I will try using MPI_BCAST. Actually I find this quite confusing all over the code, even the original part they never use MPI_BCAST. Instead MPI_SEND is called multiple times to submit the massage. I have done some research and MPI_BCAST should be more efficient. I will try using MPI_Wtime() to check the performance. Let’s see what happens.